# Create scoreboard in unity

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

Hi I'm a newbie and I have a problem... I want to create a scoreboard in Unity. My idea is to use Instantiate create objects and just change the name, score, day from the object I want to Instantiate. But when I turn on Scoreboard it dont work :((

This is my code

UserModel.cs

```
    public class UserModel : IDataModel
    {
        public int    Score;
        public string Day;
        public string Name;
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class ListPlayerModel : IDataModel
    {
        public List<UserModel> ListPlayer;
    }
```

UserController.cs

```
public void SaveDataToFile()
        {
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            using var sw = new StreamWriter(Application.persistentDataPath + "/dataUser.json");
            using JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, this.Model);
            Debug.Log("Save success");
        }
```

UserView.cs

```
private void SaveUserData()
    {
        this.Model.ListPlayer.Add(new UserModel
        {
            Score = User.Score,
            Day   = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(),
            Name  = this.nameInput.text
        });
    
        this.Controller.SaveDataToFile();
    }
```

// Scoreboard.cs

```
public void LoadDataToFile()
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Load user data from storage
            ///</summary>
            var outputJson     = File.ReadAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + "/dataUser.json");
            var loadedUserData = JsonUtility.FromJson<ListPlayerModel>(outputJson);
        
            var orderByResut = from n in loadedUserData.ListPlayer
                                orderby n.Score
                                select n;

            /// <summary>
            /// Print 3 players with the high score
            ///</summary>
            for(int i=0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                foreach (var std in orderByResut)
                {
                    ListPlayerName.text = std.Name[i].ToString();
                    ListPlayerScore.text = std.Score.ToString();
                    ListPlayerDay.text = std.Day[i].ToString();
                    UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate(ListPlayer, ListPlayer.transform.position * (i+1f), ListPlayer.transform.rotation);
                }
            }
       }
```

And when I turn on Scoreboard, Bug stand up and say: "ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`2[TElement,TKey]..ctor (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source,..."

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that ListPlayerModel actually sets up the ListPlayer list as right now I don't see anywhere that actually creates it, thus resulting in a null reference exception when you try access it with LINQ in LoadDataToFile.

You should be able to do this by tweaking ListPlayerModel from:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class ListPlayerModel : IDataModel
    {
        public List<UserModel> ListPlayer;
    }
```

To:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class ListPlayerModel : IDataModel
    {
        public List<UserModel> ListPlayer = new List<UserModel>();
    }
```

because you're serialising it might not like constructing the list like that so if it doesn't work you can always just ensure when you create a ListPlayerModel you require the ListPlayer to be setup in the constructor.